# C# input on Layout page using Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, console-application, asp.net-web-api

I've written the following code in Console. I want to display the string the code returns, on my Layout.cshtml page like any other things on the page. How can I do it using Web API?

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serverName = "localhost";

            var nsm = new ServerManager();

            using (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager sm = Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName))
            {

               //site mySite = sm.Sites.Add("Racing Cars Site", d:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\racing",  8080);
                int counter = 1; 
                foreach (var site in sm.Sites)
                {
                    //var p = site.Bindings.GetCollection().GetAttribute("physicalPath");
                    var p = site.Applications[0].VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath;
                      int b=0;

                    foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding binding in site.Bindings)
                         b= binding.EndPoint.Port;

                    Console.Write(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                        , "Site number {0} : , {1} PhysicalPath : {2}  , Port:{3} {4} "
                        , counter.ToString(), site.Name ,p , b, Environment.NewLine));
                    counter++; 
                }
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a console application? or asp.net application?

Comment: Web API has no layout pages - it has no UI and doesn't generate HTML. MVC does. What are you asking? Do you have a specific question or are you asking how to create a page in ASP.NET MVC in general?

Comment: this is console code, I want to rewrite the code anywhere possible in asp.net mvc application and get an output on my webpage, is my explanation clear enough?

Comment: You didn't mention any tag of console application.

Comment: in general, I want the C# output to be displayed on my webpage, do you think should I do it by mvc helpers or can I use Web API?

Comment: You need to create MVC application.

Comment: it's not clear enough what you're asking. What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: @ZivWeissman It doesn't clear what she's asking. Maybe she doesn't want in MVC.

Comment: I would combine MVC and Web API. I want to write this code in MVC Application and get the output on my layout page. do you think it's better to use MVC Helpers or I should try Web API? in both cases what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: @ShadiMahmoodian see the answer. It's better to use MVC helpers because you have more power in that. ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want these codes in `MVC` you need to create `MVC` application. No other way to do it, in that case.

Try to rewrite that in `MVC`. By the way if you want to show the output in the `console application` you must use `Debug` for that.

Here is the example :

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The String");
```

So it means `debug` is the `console` code in `MVC`.

Update : If you want to show the result of your codes in web pages you have to rewrite your codes in `MVC` application.

You also asked if you want to use `helpers`, so I should say you can definitely use `MVC` helpers.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `Debug` writes to any configured debug trace listeners, not the console. Even if you meant that in MVC the OP should use `Debug`, that wouldn't help at all - the messages would be lost unless you attached a trace listener. Even then, the listener would write to a local file, not the MVC page

Comment: How does any of this answer the OP's (very vague) question? BTW the edit keeps saying that you need Debug to write to the console

Comment: well I know about Debug..no I don't want to use it. Of course I'm doing it in MVC Application. in simple words, I just need my C# output on my webpage. that's all. forget about the console..I wrote that code to get a fast output. now if it's better to go with mvc helpers can you suggest me an example? and if it could be done via Web API can you give me a hint?

Comment: @ShadiMahmoodian you are asking for a tutorial. SO is a Q&A site, tutorial questions are explicitly out-of-scope. It would take several pages to write a tutorial about MVC. [ASP.NET MVC's](http://www.asp.net/mvc) site contains *a lot of tutorials*, did you try them?

Comment: @ShadiMahmoodian Of course you can use mvc helpers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I believe she's asking for tutorial, too.

Comment: @ShadiMahmoodian This is not a question. You want the tutorial and you should read about how mvc helper and web api works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just gave an example that she can use console in MVC.

Comment: @aliboy sorry for making you confused. I'm totally new in working with Asp.net MVC. I read some tutorials on MVC but when I tried to rewrite my above code in Helper.cs, got confused how to go further. I'm familiar with importing Helpers on Layout page, but I can't get it to work!

Comment: @ShadiMahmoodian So you have to get more tutorials for that. ;) Because this is only Q&A site. And if you want to know : yes, you can use mvc helpers.

Comment: I was totally aware that I can use Helpers. this is a Q&A site and I asked a question too! anyway thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your need is not related to Web API, forget about this. An ASP.NET MVC application is the way to go.
As you said, it can be done using a helper but it exists easier ways to do that. (**Using model or Viewbag**). You will also need to learn how to use the markup of the rendering engine used in your view, like Razor. I suggest you to read some tutorials, starting from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_layout.asp) for your issue, and [here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29)