# Different outputs in Console and ASP.net Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, console

I wrote the following code to fetch the list of Sites on IIS. in Console it works normally and does what I want, but in webforms when I print the output it returns all the projects that exist in visual Studio folder. how come does it happen?

```
 public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            string s;
            string serverName = "localhost";
            var nsm = new ServerManager();
            using (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager sm = Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName))
            {

                int counter = 1;
                foreach (var site in sm.Sites)
                {

                    var p = site.Applications[0].VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath;
                    int b = 0;

                    foreach (Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding binding in site.Bindings)
                        b = binding.EndPoint.Port;

                    s =  String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                        , "Site number {0} : , {1} PhysicalPath : {2}  , Port:{3} {4} "
                        , counter.ToString(), site.Name, p, b, Environment.NewLine);
                    counter++;
                    Response.Write(s);
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# input on Layout page using Web API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877725/c-sharp-input-on-layout-page-using-web-api)

Comment: this is another problem with the same code

Comment: have you tried to step through the code..? if so please state where the issue is  happening.. can you add the items in your `s` variable where you are using string.Format method to a List<string> variable then call the sort method on the list then call `Response.Write(s)`

Comment: when I run the webform code up to " using (Microsoft. Web. Administration. ServerManager..." it returns "nsm" with this value: {Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager} but it contains nothing, unlike the console version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you run your code using visual studio's in-built hosting server which can be Cassini or IIS express.

Try hosting your asp.net web application to your windows IIS and then run the application. This should give you same answer which you get in your console application.